# Having issues with Subqueries and derived tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am still extremely new at SQL and have recently been having issues with these 3 specific subqueries for several days.

This one is supposed to return 3 columns, only returns records of vendors from "CA" and uses a derived table.

```
 -- Query 6
SELECT VendorID, VendorName, Vendors.VendorState
FROM Vendors 
JOIN (SELECT VendorState 
      FROM Vendors) AS SubVendors ON Vendors.VendorID = SubVendors.VendorID
WHERE Vendors.VendorState = 'CA'
ORDER BY VendorID;
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'VendorID'.

This one returns 4 columns, also uses a derived table and the subquery is coded in the 'FROM' clause.

```
-- Query 7
SELECT 
    InvoicesMain.VendorID, 
    MAX(InvoiceTotal) AS MaxInvoice, 
    MIN(InvoiceTotal) AS MinInvoice, 
    AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AvgInvoice
FROM 
    Invoices AS InvoiceMain
JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 10 
         VendorID, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AvgInvoice
     FROM Invoices
     GROUP BY VendorID
     ORDER BY AvgInvoice DESC) AS TopVendor ON InvoicesMain.VendorID = TopVendor.VendorID)
GROUP 
    InvoicesMain.VendorID
ORDER BY 
    MaxInvoice DESC;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

And lastly, I am honestly not sure how to do this one; it is supposed to be restated as a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM 
    Invoices 
JOIN 
    InvoiceLineItems ON Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID
WHERE 
    VendorID = 122
ORDER BY 
    InvoiceDate;
```

Any tips, please?

Comment: Your first query isn't selecting the vendor ID in the SubVendors query, but you're trying to join on it. Your second query has an extra bracket after your join that needs to be removed. What's the issue with the third one? As a subquery, you'd just need to remove the order by statement and if ordering is necessary, do it outside the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

On Query 6, you didn't select the `VendorID` on your subquery, that's why the error occurred. Try this query instead:

```
SELECT VendorID, VendorName, Vendors.VendorState
FROM Vendors JOIN 
(SELECT VendorState, VendorID 
FROM Vendors) AS SubVendors
ON Vendors.VendorID = SubVendors.VendorID
WHERE V.VendorState = 'CA'
ORDER BY VendorID;
```

For Query 7 you are just missing a `)` on your subquery.

```
SELECT InvoicesMain.VendorID, MAX(InvoiceTotal) AS MaxInvoice, MIN(InvoiceTotal) AS MinInvoice, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AvgInvoice
FROM Invoices AS InvoiceMain
JOIN
(SELECT TOP 10 VendorID, AVG(InvoiceTotal)) AS AvgInvoice
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY VendorID
ORDER BY AvgInvoice DESC) AS TopVendor
ON InvoicesMain.VendorID = TopVendor.VendorID)
GROUP InvoicesMain.VendorID
ORDER BY MaxInvoice DESC;
```

For the last item, you can reinstate this as subquery by selecting `InvoiceID` from the table `InvoiceLineItems` just like in Query 6

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices JOIN 
(SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoicelineitems) As I
ON Invoices.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate;
```